# Failover on MySQL JDBC connections?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, high-availability

I am trying to determine how i could implement a high availablity solution using the MySQL JDBC driver, it seems that there is a failover property that I can set. But I am wondering what people tend to use when implement a simple failover mechanism using MySQL and JDBC?

We are planning to have 2 front Tomcat servers connected to 2 MySQL servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you're asking about JDBC, I hope this helps you understand all available options...

I typically handle failover by using a load balanced configuration that can gracefully failover, rather than at the JDBC layer.

MySQL Proxy is one way to accomplish that:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/mysql-proxy-howto.html

Comment: The infrastructure guys tell me that this involves another server, thus another layer that can fail.. is this correct according to you? I would also like to implement the proxy but need some ammo to explain the infra guys that this is the best option.

Comment: Do i need seperate servers to run the proxy?

Comment: @Marco - Actually, if you don't operate separate servers, you have a guaranteed single point of failure.  That server goes down, your solution goes down.  The comments in the link shows how you can setup two physical servers that mirror each other (one of may ways to setup high availability).

Comment: @Eric sorry to be a bit unclear, but the idea is that we have 2 sql servers and 2 tomcat servers. My remark was if i install the proxy do i need an addtional layer of servers between the tomcat and sql servers, this solely to use the proxy.

Comment: @Marco: Technically you can run the load balancer twice, once on each Tomcat box.  You risk each balancer reaching a different determination of which SQL server is actually live (for example, if there's a network glitch and they both become unavailable for a period).  I prefer two balancers, one a failover for the other, as separate boxes.  They can be virtual servers, and they can be very small compared to your main servers.